# Find Peak value using slope - android - java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to code that If the sign value of the slope changed from positive to negative, then that value indexing is my pressure peak of the sensor. and even through if it found the peak, there might be another peak because of the pressure is increasing. 
How can I do that please? Thank you in advance.

```
for (int i =1;i<strNumbers.length -2;i++){ //strNumber is the array stream from sensor.
            String y1;
            y1 = strNumbers[i];
            String y2;
            y2 = strNumbers[i+1];
            float y_2 = Float.parseFloat(y2);
            float y_1 = Float.parseFloat(y1);
            float delta_y = y_2  - y_1;
            float mySlope = 0;
            float delta_x;
            delta_x  = 1; //always difference is 1.  
             mySlope =  (delta_y / delta_x);

              activity.FirstPeak.setTextColor(Color.RED);
              activity.FirstPeak.setText(String.valueOf(mySlope));

        }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? find local max or find every peak or highest peak?

Comment: 1- highest peak (Peak pressure). 2- find Peak to peak time(and that is can be done if we know the two peaks, then we can just say what is the dataCount between the two peaks / 100 (my sampling rate)

Answer (score 0):

At each point in the loop, you need to compare two gradients - the gradient on the left, and the gradient on the right. If the left is positive, and the right is negative, then you have found a peak.

```
List<Integer> peaks = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i < strNumbers.length - 1; i++)
{
    float left = Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[i]) - Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[i - 1]);
    float right = Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[i + 1]) - Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[i]);
    if (left > 0 && right <= 0)
        peaks.add(i);
}
```

Now you have an array, containing the indices of all peaks. You can find the absolute maximum like this:

```
float max = 0;
float maxIndex = -1;
for (Integer i : peaks)
{
    float peak = Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[i]);
    if (peak > max)
    {
        max = peak;
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}
```

And you can find the peak-to-peak distances like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < peaks.size() - 1; i++)
    sum += peaks.get(i + 1) - peaks.get(i);
float average = (float)sum / (peaks.size() - 1)
```

Comment: and what if max is first or last ? then your code retrun slope not the peak

Comment: If the first or last sample happen to be the maximum, I would still call them a peak. You can either ignore them, take them as the highest value (as this solution will), or add in two slope checks to see if they could be peaks.

Comment: - Thanks for your respond. but I also want to find the peak to peak time with the use of sampling rate. so I don't know if this implementation can help me in determine two peaks. also pressure in my code is String not float. could you help me please. thanks.

Comment: Hi Mr. Andrew. That is exactly what am looking for, but I did two different code including yours (the one of left and right). but the android complains about my array and it throw an exception : -   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "" , it is referring to **float left statement**

Comment: this is my code  **float left = Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[j]) - Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[j - 1]);
                float right = Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[j + 1]) - Float.parseFloat(strNumbers[j]);
                if (left > 0 && right <= 0) {
                    peaks.add(j);
                    activity.FirstPeak.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    activity.FirstPeak.setText(String.valueOf(peaks));
                }**

Comment: You have an empty string in your array strNumbers, it is complaining because it doesn't know how to convert the empty string "" into a float

Comment: Am looking at the code for finding the max. peak **float max =0**. I'm looking to find all the peaks. not only the max max.

Comment: Did you even read the part of the answer that says **Now you have an array, containing the indices of all peaks**?

Comment: Yes, I did, but, would you mind to take a look at my array how it looks like in my second question at this link, you will have more outline explanation of what am trying to do. because am confuse with the peaks that aren't the maximum peaks. please check the graph picture: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583104/peak-between-different-peak-values

Comment: If there will be a lit peak during the numbers of array, it will also considered, - I just need all max. peaks.